# Selecting COUNT from different criteria on a table

Tags: sql, query-optimization, subquery

I have a table named 'jobs'.  For a particular user a job can be active, archived, overdue, pending, or closed.  Right now every page request is generating 5 COUNT queries and in an attempt at optimization I'm trying to reduce this to a single query.  This is what I have so far but it is barely faster than the 5 individual queries.  Note that I've simplified the conditions for each subquery to make it easier to understand, the full query acts the same however.

Is there a way to get these 5 counts in the same query without using the inefficient subqueries?

```
SELECT
  (SELECT count(*)
    FROM "jobs"
    WHERE
      jobs.creator_id = 5 AND
      jobs.status_id NOT IN (8,3,11) /* 8,3,11 being 'inactive' related statuses */
  ) AS active_count, 
  (SELECT count(*)
    FROM "jobs"
    WHERE
      jobs.creator_id = 5 AND
      jobs.due_date < '2011-06-14' AND
      jobs.status_id NOT IN(8,11,5,3) /* Grabs the overdue active jobs
                                      ('5' means completed successfully) */
  ) AS overdue_count,
  (SELECT count(*)
    FROM "jobs"
    WHERE
      jobs.creator_id = 5 AND
      jobs.due_date BETWEEN '2011-06-14' AND '2011-06-15 06:00:00.000000'
  ) AS due_today_count
```

This goes on for 2 more subqueries but I think you get the idea.

Is there an easier way to collect this data since it's basically 5 different COUNT's off of the same subset of data from the jobs table?

The subset of data is 'creator_id = 5', after that each count is basically just 1-2 additional conditions.  Note that right now we're using Postgres but may be moving to MySQL in the near future.  So if you can provide an ANSI-compatible solution I'd be gratetful :)

Comment: You could create a subquery or join to a new table that will separate everything into 3 groups, and then do a COUNT / GROUP BY on the groups.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the typical solution. Use a case statement to break out the different conditions. If a record meets it gets a 1 else a 0. Then do a `SUM` on the values

```
  SELECT
    SUM(active_count) active_count,
    SUM(overdue_count) overdue_count
    SUM(due_today_count) due_today_count
  FROM 
  (

  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN jobs.status_id NOT IN (8,3,11) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END active_count,
    CASE WHEN jobs.due_date < '2011-06-14' AND jobs.status_id NOT IN(8,11,5,3)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  overdue_count,
    CASE WHEN jobs.due_date BETWEEN '2011-06-14' AND '2011-06-15 06:00:00.000000' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  due_today_count

    FROM "jobs"
    WHERE
      jobs.creator_id = 5 ) t
```

UPDATE
As noted when 0 records are returned as t this result in as single result of Nulls in all the values. You have three options

1) Add A Having clause so that you have No records returned rather than result of all NULLS

```
   HAVING SUM(active_count) is not null
```

2) If you want all zeros returned than you could add coalesce to all your sums

For example

```
 SELECT
      COALESCE(SUM(active_count)) active_count,
       COALESCE(SUM(overdue_count)) overdue_count
      COALESCE(SUM(due_today_count)) due_today_count
```

3) Take advantage of the fact that `COUNT(NULL) = 0` as sbarro's demonstrated. You should note that the not-null value could be anything it doesn't have to be a 1

for example

```
 SELECT
      COUNT(CASE WHEN 
            jobs.status_id NOT IN (8,3,11) THEN 'Manticores Rock' ELSE NULL
       END) as [active_count]
```

Comment: I like this method, you can add additional criteria as needed.

Comment: I like this solution :)  I'll investigate it for my problem before accepting it though.

Comment: Postgres required me to add `END` statements to each `CASE`.  Is this standard SQL or something postgres decided to require?  `CASE WHEN jobs.status_id = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END active_count` otherwise it threw exceptions at me.

Comment: @nzignab that wasn't unique to postgres. That was me being forgetful. I updated the answer

Comment: Just wanted to note that this dropped execution time by about 75%, thanks :D

Comment: @Conrad hmm using SUM() in this manner will return all NULL's if the WHERE jobs.creator_id = 5 has no results (I think that's the cause, not 100% sure).  If you change it to use `COUNT` and remove the `ELSE 0` (as was done in rsbarro's answer) then it'll make those 0's instead.  It was doing weird things when my code got `nil` instead of `0`

Answer (score 13):

I would use this approach, use COUNT in combination with CASE WHEN.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN 
        jobs.status_id NOT IN (8,3,11) THEN 1 
    END) as [Count1],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN 
        jobs.due_date < '2011-06-14' 
        AND jobs.status_id NOT IN(8,11,5,3) THEN 1
    END) as [COUNT2],
    COUNT(CASE WHEN
            jobs.due_date BETWEEN '2011-06-14' AND '2011-06-15 06:00:00.000000'
    END) as [COUNT3]
FROM 
    "jobs"
WHERE 
     jobs.creator_id = 5
```

Comment: I would imagine performance is similar, even though this approach only uses 1 SELECT.

Comment: +1 but I'd still use sum e.g. `SUM(CASE WHEN jobs.status_id NOT IN (8,3,11) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`. Using `COUNT` takes advantage of the fact that `COUNT` ignores nulls which not everyone realizes.

Comment: @Conrad: Good point. I think that decision just comes down to personal preference. There's something to me that's more clear about seeing COUNT when you're trying to get a count of something, but either approach works fine.

Comment: ) I know what you mean **SUM** (active_count) active_ **count** looks funny

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

[SQL Server 2012 introduced the `IIF` logical function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql). Using SQL Server 2012 or greater you can now use this new function instead of a `CASE` expression. The `IIF` function also works with *Azure SQL Database* (but at the moment it does not work with *Azure SQL Data Warehouse* or *Parallel Data Warehouse*). It's shorthand for the `CASE` expression.

I find myself using the `IIF` function rather than the `CASE` expression when there is only one case. This alleviates the pain of having to write `CASE WHEN condition THEN x ELSE y END` and instead writing it as `IIF(condition, x, y)`. If multiple conditions may be met (multiple `WHEN`s), you should instead consider using the regular `CASE` expression rather than nested `IIF` functions.

> Returns one of two values, depending on whether the Boolean expression
>   evaluates to true or false in SQL Server.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> IIF ( boolean_expression, true_value, false_value )
> ```
>
> ### Arguments
>
> `boolean_expression`
>  A valid Boolean expression.
>
> If this argument is not a Boolean expression, then a syntax error is
>   raised.
>
> `true_value`
>  Value to return if `boolean_expression` evaluates to
>   true.
>
> `false_value`
>  Value to return if `boolean_expression` evaluates
>   to false.
>
> ### Remarks
>
> `IIF` is a shorthand way for writing a `CASE` expression. It evaluates
>   the Boolean expression passed as the first argument, and then returns
>   either of the other two arguments based on the result of the
>   evaluation. That is, the `true_value` is returned if the Boolean
>   expression is true, and the `false_value` is returned if the Boolean
>   expression is false or unknown. `true_value` and `false_value` can be
>   of any type. The same rules that apply to the `CASE` expression for
>   Boolean expressions, null handling, and return types also apply to
>   `IIF`. For more information, see [`CASE` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql).
>
> The fact that `IIF` is translated into `CASE` also has an impact on
>   other aspects of the behavior of this function. Since `CASE`
>   expressions can be nested only up to the level of 10, `IIF` statements
>   can also be nested only up to the maximum level of 10. Also, `IIF` is
>   remoted to other servers as a semantically equivalent `CASE`
>   expression, with all the behaviors of a remoted `CASE` expression.

---

### Code

Implementation of the `IIF` function in SQL would resemble the following (using the same logic presented by [@rsbarro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/342113/rsbarro) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6350268/3600709)):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(
        IIF(jobs.status_id NOT IN (8,3,11), 1, 0)
    ) as active_count,
    COUNT(
        IIF(jobs.due_date < '2011-06-14' AND jobs.status_id NOT IN(8,11,5,3), 1, 0)
    ) as overdue_count,
    COUNT(
        IIF(jobs.due_date BETWEEN '2011-06-14' AND '2011-06-15 06:00:00.000000', 1, 0)
    ) as due_today_count
FROM 
    "jobs"
WHERE 
     jobs.creator_id = 5
```